# Grid com espaçamento e BoxView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou aprendendo a utilizar Grid e tenho três dúvidas no meu projeto que mesmo nos testes ou ao acompanhar tutoriais não consegui bons resultados na prática já que sempre vi sendo feito testes com BoxView:

1. Qual a melhor forma de dar espaço entre os componentes? Porque se utilizo `HorizontalOption` basicamente eu teria apenas 3 controles (`Start`, `Center` e `End`), e isso é ruim pra mim já que normalmente utilizo mais; mas se utilizo `Margin` não iria ser diferente o espaçamento dependendo da quantia de megapixel na tela do aparelho testado, podendo assim ficar bom no meu aparelho mas num outro deformado?
2. Quero utilizar um `BoxView` na Grid para separar as linhas do `ListView` e obter uma melhor visualização, mas não estou conseguindo e deixarei o código para, se possível, me ajudarem.
3. Ao visualizarem o código estará nítido que utilizo uma `Label Data:` que nem aparece no `ListView`, gostaria de saber o motivo.

Imagem de como está esse meu projeto:

[image: ListView]

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="lstCompra"  
              BackgroundColor="LightGray"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <!--  HasUnevenRows = Serve para fazer com que o conteúdo digitado não seja cortado -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- DataTemplate  = exibe dados de uma coleção de objetos em um ListView -->
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>

                        <!-- Colunas -->
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- Linhas -->
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- Código -->
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="Código:"
                               FontSize="Small"
                               BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                               Margin="2, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{Binding ID_SOLCOMPRA}" 
                               FontSize="Small"
                               BackgroundColor="Green"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               Margin="50, 0, 0, 0"/>

                        <!-- Data -->
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="Data:"
                               FontSize="Small"
                               BackgroundColor="LightCyan"
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding DT_CADASTRO}" 
                               FontSize="Small"
                               BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               HorizontalOptions="End"/>

                        <!-- Repartir conteudo com cor -->
                        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" 
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                 BackgroundColor="Red"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**A documentação do Xamarin oferece uma explicação geral sobre esse layout**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid), então vamos direto às suas perguntas:

> 1. Qual a melhor forma de dar espaço entre os componentes? Porque se utilizo HorizontalOption basicamente eu teria apenas 3 controles (Start, Center e End), e isso é ruim pra mim já que normalmente utilizo mais; mas se utilizo Margin não iria ser diferente o espaçamento dependendo da quantia de megapixel na tela do aparelho testado, podendo assim ficar bom no meu aparelho mas num outro deformado?

Somente fazendo um adendo: eu sou contra discursos que tentam imprimir opinião sobre o que é ou não 'melhor'. Posso sugerir algumas formas, mas o adjetivo que atribuiria a elas seria '**possíveis**' (não necessariamente melhor). Podem existir outras. Podem ou não ser melhores, não pretendo entrar nesse mérito. Acho que cada situação determinará o que seria 'melhor' **para você** naquele caso.

O `HorizontalOptions` não determina uma localização fixa. Ele determina um comportamento de posicionamento de um elemento dentro de um container.

No entanto, outros fatores ajudam a determinar o posicionamento final do elemento. Por exemplo, no seu caso, cada célula do `Grid` faz o papel de container, porém esse layout **permite sobreposição**, e isso faz com que `HorizontalOptions="Start"` em mais de um elemento (supondo que tenham o mesmo tamanho) faça com um fique sobre o outro. Daí a necessidade de se usar artifícios como `Margin` para esse caso.

Um outra alternativa é você usar dentro da célula um `StackLayout` com `Orientation="Horizontal"`, que fará com que os elementos sejam posicionados **sequencialmente** (o `StackLayout` não poermite sobreposição).

Em geral, quando eu uso `Grid` eu sempre opto por definir uma grade (quantidade de linhas e colunas) onde cada elemento individual ocupe sozinho uma célula e outros que precisam sobrepor em determinados momentos são definidos a ocupar mas de uma linha/coluna.

> 2. Quero utilizar um BoxView na Grid para separar as linhas do ListView e obter uma melhor visualização, mas não estou conseguindo e deixarei o código para, se possível, me ajudarem.

De acordo com a sua definição do `BoxView` (`Grid.Row="1"`, `Grid.Column="0"` e `Grid.ColumnSpan="1"`), ele vai estar na primeira coluna, segunda linha, e ocupar somente 1 coluna de largura (é o comportamento padrão).

Acho que sua intenção nesse caso era que ele ocupasse duas colunas (`Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`).

> 3. Ao visualizarem o código estará nítido que utilizo uma Label Data: que nem aparece no ListView, gostaria de saber o motivo.

[Nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/303003/78713) eu mencionei que o `Grid` permite sobreposição de conteúdo. Este é exatamente o motivo, o label que tem o texto "Data:" foi sobreposto pelo outro que está definido na mesma posição.

Com tudo isso respondido, uma ***possível*** solução para definir o seu layout seria essa:

```
<ViewCell>
    <Grid>

        <!-- Colunas -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Linhas -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Código -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" 
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Padding="2"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Código:"
                   FontSize="Small"
                   BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ID_SOLCOMPRA}" 
                   FontSize="Small"
                   BackgroundColor="Green"
                   TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Data -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" 
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Padding="2"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Data:"
                   FontSize="Small"
                   BackgroundColor="LightCyan"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding DT_CADASTRO}" 
                   FontSize="Small"
                   BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Repartir conteudo com cor -->
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" 
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 BackgroundColor="Red"/>

    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Espero que isso ajude.